# Java http post: values arent added

Tags: java, http-post

I try to send post request, but webserver returns that I added no post-values. I spent a lot of time trying to solve this issue, but no result. Here is the code:

```
    public static String post(String url, String postParams)
{
    URLConnection connection = null;
    try
    {
        connection = initializeConnection(url);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        ((HttpURLConnection) connection).setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(postParams.getBytes());

        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        // Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        return inputStreamToString(is);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}

protected static HttpURLConnection initializeConnection(String stringUrl)
{
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    URL url = null;
    try
    {
        url = new URL(stringUrl);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return connection;
}

public static String inputStreamToString(InputStream is)
{
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try
    {
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
        {
            total.append(line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return total.toString();
}
```

I receive a message from webserver where it is told that no post-values are added. As far as I understand from the code, the values are added. I'm stuck.

Comment: use Wireshark or Fiddler to check the data transmission on the network layer.

Comment: In the debugger, have you verified that postParams contains data and the result of calling getBytes() on it is providing you with data?

Comment: check whether are you getting postParams in your post method...
Seems like code is okay...

Comment: Try setting the content type to `text/html`. Try simple post params `"x=y\r\n"`. BTW many examples use DataOutputStream, but better would be `new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "ISO-8859-1")))`.

Comment: FileOutputStream? Did you mean: new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "ISO-8859-1").write(postParams) ???

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that all I had to do was to replace

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
```

with

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

So simple and so much time spent to clear it out...
By the way, how could I know that server requires this header? I thought that all the work that is essential to the request would be automatically done by java..

P.S. Installing fiddler helped to solve the issue, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

debug the 'postParams' parameter and check what been sent.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I agree, but he can't write comments yet.